# Javascript code end of webpage with Spring and Dojo

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, dojo, spring-webflow

I have a pretty specific issue to deal with : I am looking for a solution about IE6 crashing when there is too much javascript in a webpage. The project I am working on is using Dojo, SpringJS, Apache Tiles and Spring Webflow. For each field used (defined in .tagx files), the decoration is added as following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Spring.addDecoration(
    new Spring.ElementDecoration({
        elementId : '_${field}_id', 
        widgetType : 'dijit.form.ValidationTextBox', 
        widgetAttrs : {
            <!-- Widget attrs -->
        }
    })
);
</script>
```

So, in the generated webpage, a lot of javascript is added everywhere. The problem is IE6 seems to crash when there is too much javascript. The solution "experts" found was to write all the javascript code at the end of the HTML page.

In intent to do that, I tried to create a new tag called putScriptInCache.tagx :

```
<jsp:useBean id="mapScripts" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>
    <jsp:doBody var="theBody" />
    <c:set target="${mapScripts}" property="${id}" value="${theBody}"/>
```

Which replaces previous javascript tag :

```
<lbputil:putScriptInCache id="${field}">
    Spring.addDecoration(
        new Spring.ElementDecoration({
            elementId : '_${field}_id', 
            widgetType : 'dijit.form.ValidationTextBox', 
            widgetAttrs : {
                <!-- Widget attrs -->
            }
        })
    );
</lbputil:putScriptInCache>
```

Finally, I have written a piece of code which loops on the map created and write javascript at the end of the html body :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
        <c:forEach items="${mapScripts}" var="script">
            <c:out value="${script.value}" escapeXml="false" />
        </c:forEach>
        });
</script>
```

It seems to work pretty well but an issue remains : when an ajax request is fired, an Apache Tiles fragment of the jsp is reloaded using Spring Webflow. After that, I noticed that the map in request scope was empty and I can't figure out why. It should have been filled with the reloaded fragment fields javascript code.

EDIT : If someone has a totally different way to solve my initial issue, do not hesitate to propose it !

Answer (score 0):

After lookep at the spring-dojo.js, I found that this script already evaluates scripts at the end of the fragment rendering.

```
handleResponse: function(response, ioArgs, callbackResponse) {
        //...

        //Extract and store all <script> elements from the response
        var scriptPattern = '(?:<script(.|[\n|\r])*?>)((\n|\r|.)*?)(?:<\/script>)';
        var extractedScriptNodes = [];
        var matchAll = new RegExp(scriptPattern, 'img');
        var matchOne = new RegExp(scriptPattern, 'im');

        var scriptNodes = response.match(matchAll);
        if (scriptNodes != null)
        {
            for (var i=0; i<scriptNodes.length; i++)
            {
                var script = (scriptNodes[i].match(matchOne) || ['','',''])[2];
                script = script.replace(/<!--/mg,'').replace(/\/\/-->/mg,'').replace(/<!\[CDATA\[(\/\/>)*/mg,'').replace(/(<!)*\]\]>/mg,'');
                extractedScriptNodes.push(script);
            }
        }
        //...

        //Evaluate any script code
        dojo.forEach(extractedScriptNodes, function(script){
            dojo.eval(script);
        });

        // APPEL du callBackResponse
        if (callbackResponse != null){
            callbackResponse();
        }

        return response;
    },
```

First, it stores script tags into *extractedScriptNodes*, then it replaces the script tags with  *// Original script removed to avoid re-execution* . Finally, it evaluates each *extractedScriptNodes* after having rendered the view.

So, it should already work...